# ¿Cómo actualizar un estatus específico en php myadmin?

Tags: sql

Estoy realizando un update para cambiar el estatus de mi usuario de activo a baja o viceversa. Actualmente se actualiza toda la tabla y no solo el campo en especifico

Mi consulta está así:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `usuario` SET `idestaus` = '\'activo\'' WHERE `usuario`.`id_usuario` =  `usuario`.`id_usuario`";
$result =$conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: debes especificar el id del usuario que quieres actualizar hay los esas haciendo de manera global a todos. ejemplo `... where usuario.id_usuario = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Si le dices que haga el UPDATE para todas las filas en las que

```
WHERE `usuario`.`id_usuario` =  `usuario`.`id_usuario`
```

significa que, para todas las filas, esa condición es cierta. Finalmente, el campo id_usuario VA A SER igual a el campo id_usuario.

Revisa la condición que quieres  validar para actualizar sólo un estatus dado.

Comment: como tomo su id dircto de cada usuario aplicaco a php?

Comment: @JesusVelazquez nos tienes que mostrar el resto del código en ese script. En algún momento identificas a tu usuario? Cargas sus datos desde la BD? Con lo que pusiste en la pregunta no tenemos cómo ayudarte. Y si vas a añadir algo, edita la pregunta; acá abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta